# View Controller with Multiple sub views

Tags: xcode, ipad

I have a website page which I need to replicate in my app (as a reference for anyone that wants to help the url is http://www.sccgformulary.co.uk/gis.html) There is a title, some sub-headings, plenty of text in different sections and a few different tables. The colouring in the background isn't needed.

My question is how would this be implemented in Interface Builder (if it is even possible?) I don't know how to design the layout of a page which extends further than 1 screen. I've done it before programatically - is this the only way to design views which need a scrollview with multiple subviews? any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably a [simple UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/).

You might need some way of feeding data to your application via a web service. [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is popular. but before you go ahead I suggest you read up on UITableView and look at some similar Apps to find out exactly what you want.

Comment: The website wont ever be changed, so I can hard-code the data in xcode - its purely the formatting of the layout ive got issues with. Ill have a look at the link and get back to you!